# How to insert image in a mock up?

Tags: svg, mockups

In a laptop mockup or a phone mockup or others any kind of mockup, I want to insert an external image is there any script PHP or javascript like my idea? I already found some site are doing same. How do I build it? Can anyone give me some idea?

My example site is http://magicmockups.com/mockup/10/

Comment: That link does not work. I have some Imagemagick bash unix shell scripts that will put images onto t-shirts and coffee mugs and have put images onto cell phones. See my scripts, tshirt and cylinderize, for example at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. For commercial use, they would need to be licensed. They can be run from PHP exec() commands. You would have to build the web user interface.

Comment: I think I am not searching this script. Just update the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Imagemagick's perspective distortion after you measure the corners in both images.

Background:

[image]

Image:

[image]

Command (Unix syntax):

```
convert background.png \
\( monet2.jpg -virtual-pixel none +distort perspective "0,0 317,99  265,0 540,85  265,333 594,426  0,333 342,446" \) \
-layers merge +repage monet2_background.jpg
```

If on Windows, remove the \ before ( and before ) and change the end of line \ to ^.

Result:
[image]

You can run this from PHP exec() or recode it in PHP Imagick syntax.

Comment: How did you calculate the perspective for the mockup ?

Comment: Manually measured the corners of the quadrilateral in the the cell phone and used the corners of the input image.

Comment: Python version of this script available here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/77215981/2836621

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP image processing libraries such as [PHP GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

Comment: Yes, this is for converting image but how do I insert the image that specific place? Do I have to make the full mockup in SVG?