# How to distort an image using wand

Tags: python-3.x, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to the same that was asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52090350/how-to-insert-image-in-a-mock-up) old question but in `python` using `wand`.

so far I have done the following:

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display

# Paths to your input images
background_path = 'background.png'
source_path = 'source.jpg'
output_path = 'output.jpg'

# Open the background image
with Image(filename=background_path) as background:
    # Open the source image (source)
    with Image(filename=source_path) as source:
        # Define the distortion points
        distortion_points = (
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            265, 0, 540, 85,
            265, 333, 594, 426,
            0, 333, 342, 446
        )

        # Apply the perspective distortion to the blank image
        source.distort('perspective', distortion_points)

        # Composite the background image onto the distorted source
        background.composite(source, 317, 99)

        # Save the resulting image
        background.save(filename=output_path)

display(Image(filename='output.jpg'))
```

The `flower` image is distorted and the pixel aren't aligned.

Any idea on how to achieve the same only in python?

EDIT:

This is the current status

current result
[image: Current result]

expected result
[image: Expected result]

background image
[image: Background image]

source image

[image: Source image]

Thanks

Comment: Please click [edit] and ensure you provide the input image and the current and expected output image - i.e. 3 images. Saying *"the pixels aren't aligned"* does not describe the issues very clearly. Thank you.

Comment: Done, Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do it more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display

# Paths to your input images
background_path = 'background.jpg'
source_path = 'source.jpg'
output_path = 'output.jpg'

# Open the background image
with Image(filename=background_path) as background:
    # Open the source image (source)
    with Image(filename=source_path) as source:
        # Define the distortion points
        distortion_points = (
            0, 0, 317, 99,
            265, 0, 540, 85,
            265, 333, 594, 426,
            0, 333, 342, 446
        )
        # See https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/guide/distortion.html
        source.virtual_pixel = 'transparent'
        source.artifacts['distort:viewport'] = f'{background.width}x{background.height}+0+0'

        # Apply the perspective distortion to the blank image
        source.distort('perspective', distortion_points)

        # Composite the distorted source onto the background
        background.composite(source, 0, 0)

        # Save the resulting image
        background.save(filename=output_path)

display(Image(filename='output.jpg'))
```

[image]